# Suggestions for tools for tracing or profiling C++ console app execution and diffing traces

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, profiling, trace

I want to perform a trace of the executions of [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) with two different sets of command arguments and diff the results so that I can see why different paths are taken through the code.

On my Win32 XP SP3 box, the two commands `nmap -F -v -d -n <target_host>` and `nmap -F -v -v -d -n <target_host>` should take almost the same path through the code (excepting the handling of the extra `-v` arg), but they do not.  I found that there was some issue with a call to `getAdapterAddresses` returning `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` which resulted in nmap quitting with an error message which differed with slightly different arguments.  I've submitted a patch which seems to solve the getAdapterAddresses issue, but now I want to find-out why the app exited at different places (see this [nmap-dev mailing-list post](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2011/q4/45), and its follow-ups for more background).

The project is set-up for Visual Studio Express 2010 VC++ and I'm looking for a way to trace execution on the aforementioned windows box and then diff the results.

What tools should I be hunting for?

Comment: For system calls, you could try [STraceNT](http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=strace.htm). For library calls, check out Sysinterals's [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Comment: Thanks @KerrekSB, I really need to trace nmap functions, but I'll try your suggestions and see if anything good comes of them.

Comment: STraceNT produced two outputs ca. 1GB that had barely a line in common, so not very useful.

Comment: Interesting. Well, if the system calls are all different, then I assume that the program does indeed take very different code paths in the two scenarios.

Comment: the paths should at least be the same until it gets to argument parsing. i think i need to trace nmap function calls only - processmon also gave me output which is vastly different and difficult to match-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 [Premium](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/premium/features) and [Ultimate](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate/features) editions have a great tool for profiling from which the various elements of the generated reports can be exported (csv or xml).

I exported the call tree to csv and diff'd them with [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) and this has helped me a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

If no one comes up with something better, you can use LukeStackwalker to do this, it generates visual call graphs from the code it profiles, so you can easily compare these visually (along with the call counts and time spent in the functions over the number of samples it takes).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I found LukeStackwalker to be not very useful for comparison between two traces.  I started off by running the same command several times and diffing the resultant .lsd files - I found that the sampling was quite different in each case an I guess this is the crux of the problem for the stack sampling approach.  I found the call graphs to be more than useless for comparison too.  I also had to make nmap.main sleep for 5 seconds otherwise it would finish before LS was even ready to begin sampling.